# How to format PHP array to string

Tags: php

I have this php array:

```
$items = array (
    "Item 1" => "Value 1",
    "Item 2" => "Value 2",
    "Item 3" => "Value 3"
);
```

And I am wondering if there is an elegant PHP function I have never heard of to do the same as this:

```
$output = "";
foreach ( $items as $key => $value ) {
    $output .= sprintf( "%s: %s\n" , $key , $value );
}
echo $output;
```

Which of course, would output:

```
Item 1: Value 1
Item 2: Value 2
Item 3: Value 3
```

Also, what do you call that? Deserialization?

Comment: do you need something like `var_dump` or `print_r` ?

Comment: This wouldn't really output what you want since you reaffect `$output` to the current value every time.

Comment: there are scripts to format print_r, but you may as well do it as above, looks fine to me

Comment: if you are looking for a way to print array to be visually nice, use `echo '<pre>'; print_r(array); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: It should be with ".=" isn't it? So: $output .= sprintf();

Comment: Or echo print_r(array,1);

Comment: It would actually be called "serialization", although I don't know of any official format that looks exactly like that.

Comment: well no serialize  keeps type and structure, this does not

Comment: Something like [this](http://ideone.com/lqlyq2) ? Note that it doesn't support multidimensional arrays. You're better off using `print_r`

Comment: Something with `array_reduce`? http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: Also [`vfprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vfprintf.php), but PHP is really poor with anything, including stream logic, so I haven't found a way to get stream into a variable.

Comment: try `print_r($yourarray, true)`

Comment: Hey!  I fixed the error in the code.  That wasn't related to my question, I was more wondering if there was a way to convert the array into a formatted string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is always the [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function. Your example might look something like this:

```
function test_print($value, $key) {
    echo sprintf( "%s: %s\n" , $key , $value );
}

$items = array (
    "Item 1" => "Value 1",
    "Item 2" => "Value 2",
    "Item 3" => "Value 3"
);

array_walk($items, 'test_print');
```

After defining your function, you can then reuse `array_walk($items, 'test_print');` as needed throughout your code.

There is also the [`array_walk_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function, if you're dealing with multidimensional arrays.

Comment: This is a really great way to do it. I like simplifying it a bit, it makes the code more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your solution except that you're missing a concatenation operator.

```php
$output = "";
foreach ( $items as $key => $value ) {
    $output .= sprintf( "%s: %s\n" , $key , $value );
}
echo $output;
```

Bare in mind that this only handles single dimension arrays.

There are so many built-in functions in PHP that we sometimes forget that we actually have to write code. It was mentioned in the comments that you could use one of the array_* functions, such as [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), but that will only lead to more complexity compared to your solution.