# passing parameters to python script via php

Tags: php, python

I am trying to pass some parameters to a python script via a php script. Here is the code:

```
$item=array(
    '--native-libs-dir' => "/home/gdqupqmy/quikklyLib/",
    '--type' => "template0001style1",
    '--data'=> "12345",
    '--join' => "horizontal",
    '--output-file' => "/home/gdqupqmy/quikklyLib/saavr-12345.svg");

echo shell_exec("python quikkly-generate-code.py '$item'");
```

The python script creates an svg image file.

So far, I have had no luck. Any help would be great. And thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So obviously you can't drop an array into a string and expect output, but similarly you shouldn't just drop a string into a command either. You need to [escape your values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to prevent possible problems from arising due to special characters, whitespace etc.

Just run through the array and build a command line string like this:

```
$item = array(
    '--native-libs-dir' => "/home/gdqupqmy/quikklyLib/",
    '--type' => "template0001style1",
    '--data'=> "12345",
    '--join' => "horizontal",
    '--output-file' => "/home/gdqupqmy/quikklyLib/saavr-12345.svg"
);
$args = "";
foreach ($item as $k=>$v) {
    $args .= " $k " . escapeshellarg($v);
}
$cmd = "/usr/bin/python /full/path/to/quikkly-generate-code.py $args";
$result = exec($cmd, $output, $return);
printf("Command exited with code %d, full output follows: %s", $return, print_r($output,1));
```

This ensures all values are quoted and escaped. (I've made the assumption that the array keys are fixed values and so are not dangerous, if this is not the case they can be run through `escapeshellarg` as well.)

Comment: tried this and am still not recieving the output file

Comment: Is Python file in the same directory as PHP? Specify full paths to both the Python executable and the source file.

Comment: is there anyway I can see the python error messages? I am not getting any from php.

Comment: Use exec instead, see edit. It's more likely that you're not running python. Make sure you're using the full path, as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/gdqupqmy/public_html/test.php on line 23
Command exited with code 2, full output follows: Array

Comment: See edit, forgot to stringify the array, which should be fairly obvious from the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191332/discussion-between-ggntc-and-miken32).

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the argument string you're creating is formatted with spaces separating the keys and values. Including the variable `$item` in the command string won't do it. Instead, you should use an approach similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17396483/735204) to build a string containing your CLI argument names and arguments separated by spaces.

An untested example:

```
$arguments = "";
foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
    $arguments .= sprintf(" %s %s" , $key , $value);
}
echo shell_exec("python quikkly-generate-code.py $arguments")
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please upvote and accept it. This shows future readers experiencing similar problems that this approach is valid. If it doesn't solve your problem, please let me know in the comments so I can edit the answer for correctness.